# Ajax PHP Long Polling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this simple long polling:

```
  function poll(){
         $.ajax({
             ...
             success: function(res){
                $('#count').html(res);
                poll();
             }
        });
     }
 poll();
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
$count = $_SESSION['count'];
session_write_close();
while(true){
    session_start();
    $newcount = $_SESSION['count'];
    session_write_close();
    if($newcount != $count){
        $count = $newcount;
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
echo $count;
```

when ever the count session is updated it break out of the while sleep loop then echoes the new count then polls again. My questions is: is this right? does this code have side effects to the server?

Comment: Yes it calls frequently to server and may causes server over head if more users are using this.

Comment: You should use websockets instead of long polling. It's 2016, come on. For example with pusher it's a really easy task to do

Comment: @balping i don't want to use websockets.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i will just request when the `$_SESSION['count']` is changed.It keeps the connection open until $_SESSION['count'] is changed

Comment: How can you define number of `ajax` calls by server side `session` variable?

Comment: You have to make like every 5 min update by ajax.with less over head Then can do it by ajax else you have to use socket.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi as i have said, i don't want to use sockets

Comment: Then use ajax update on `setInterval` with 5min.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i don't want to use `setInterval` as well, i want to finish the request when the `$_SESSION['count']` is changed. Have you even tried to reproduce my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100270/discussion-between-john-pangilinan-and-parth-trivedi).